# Алгоритм разделения прямоугольника на области для каждой точки

Tags: алгоритм, диаграммы, вычислительная-геометрия

Где-то видел алгоритм с визуализацией, но уже забыл и не могу найти.

Есть прямоугольник, на нем - некоторым образом расположены точки. Нужно для каждой точки отчертить/определить границу (для простоты - прямой отрезок) соседних областей. Каждая граница должна быть равноудалена от точек областей, между которыми она проведена/определена.

Насколько помню, метод называется "метод береговой линии". По плоскости идет сканирующая прямая, при встрече точки вычисляется пересечение парабол. С подробностями прошу помочь. Или дайте ссылку на описание алгоритма.

Comment: Хорошо бы добавить метку типа "разбиение-прямоугольника" к вопросу.

Comment: [Диаграмма Вороного](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE) ?

Comment: Да, точно. Оно! Спасибо, @MaxU.

Comment: @YonTerus, добавлять уникальную метку, которая с большой вероятностью будет использоваться только в одном вопросе (в этом) - не очень хорошая идея.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В качестве ответа сошлюсь на англоязычный stackoverflow, там даже реализация есть.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346148/fastest-way-to-get-the-set-of-convex-polygons-formed-by-voronoi-line-segments/